# How to include data having date format in uitable

Tags: matlab-guide

I try to import a excel data in uitable by using pushbutton in matlab gui. The 1st column consists of date, while importing the first column is replaced by second column and the last column remains empty. My code is given below, kindly help me to solve this issue.

```
function pushbuttonLoadData_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbuttonLoadData (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.output = hObject;
filename=uigetfile({'*.xls';'*.csv'});
handles.filename=filename;
[data,colNames] = xlsread(filename);
class(colNames)
size(colNames)
colNames{1,1}
set(handles.uitable1,'Data',data,'ColumnName',colNames(1,:));
```

Comment: Maybe using Latex might help

Comment: Dear Lati, could you please elaborate it. How latex will help?

Comment: Can you please provide an example xls file (Sorry for late response, quite busy month)